# Why does not Polish for Google API in cloud flare work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, cloudflare

I am using Google Places API Web Service in my website to auto complete the location in map

Ounce I enable Polish in cloud flare, the autocomplete does not work

[image]

I am using below code to auto complete the location

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="pac-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="برای تسریع عملیات، منطقه موردنظر خود را وارد کنید.   مثال: نارمک" lang="fa" class="form-control input-sm binput" name="district_title" value="" style="height: 35px"/>
```

JAVAScript

```
var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        //gmap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($(input).parent()[0]);
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
            gmap.fitBounds(bounds);
            gmap.setZoom(15);
        });
        find_loc.show();



    }
    $('#pac-input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    function deleteOverlays() {
        if (markersArray) {
            for (var i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markersArray.length = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minify for Javascript can cause these sorts of errors.
we have to remove minify in cloudflare
```

[image]

we might be able to write a page rule to disable performance for that URL whilst leaving it on for the rest of the site by default.
Or turn if off entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that rocket.js from Cloudflare was the reason and not minification of the code.

Try disabling it in your Cloudflare panel.